# How is <del> tag interpreted by search engines?

Tags: html

What I'm wondering is will such html code:

```
Product Name 
<del> lead </del>
<del> mercury </del>
```

Be somewhat interpreted by the browsers as "product without mercury" or "product mercury free"? Will it show in the results for such queries? Or is it strictly interpreted as editorial marks?

Comment: Note that `<s>` is more appropriate than `<del>` here. `<del>` means "the original document had this text and it has been amended to remove this text", which is presumably not what is being conveyed here.

Answer (score 2):

Google just indexes the content of these tags, which makes sense, because it is visible content to the page visitor.

[Barry Schwartz](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-strike-del-tag-18000.html) has done an experiment last year to proof this, inspired by [this Google Webmaster discussion thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/c5lffPMJr3c/discussion) in which someone asked more or less the same question as you did.

The outcome was that a piece of garbage text in `<del>` tags was quickly picked up by Google News, and later also showed up in organic search results.

Of course other search engines might handle this differently, and I also don't know if those tags affect the weight of the match.

So, they do match the content, but to index this content as a 'lead free product', Google would first have to know that this is a product in the first place. The fact that there is a product name doesn't mean that Google will automatically know this.

I think a better way to tell indexers about your product is to use microformats like [h-product](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-product) or maybe even [h-recipe](http://microformats.org/wiki/hrecipe). And/or add the actual text 'mercury-free' to your product page and use markup and CSS to show it as <strike>mercury</strike>.

Comment: _“or maybe even h-recipe”_ – for those instances where a food does not have _mercury_ as an ingredient :-) There seems no way to specify for an `h-product ` whether it contains certain components or not. But I like your idea of using “mercury[-]free” in the HTML and then displaying only the “mercury” part striked-out … that at least transports the information that the product is mercury-free to search engines.

Answer (score 1):

The `<del>`-tag is usually used to denote deleted text and is often (but need not be) rendered with strike-through text. How search engines interpret this markup (and if at all) is completely up to the vendor. You may test with different search engines, but there is no general standard for markup interpretation. In fact, page ranking algorithms are often a company secret.